# Can we find and replace text from PDF using Java API

Tags: java, file, pdf, apache-poi, itext

I want to replace text from the pdf using `Java API`

I am using `PdfStamper`

Here is my code:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader((request.getRealPath("") + "/downloads/files/myfile.pdf"));
PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(request.getRealPath("") + "/downloads/files/changetextPdf.pdf"));
AcroFields form = stamp.getAcroFields(); 
form.setField("employee","staff");
stamp.setFormFlattening(true);
stamp.close();
```

Above code created Pdf, But was text not replaced.

Comment: You say you want to *replace text* but in your code you set the contents of some *form field*. Now which is what you want to do. It might help if you provided a sample pdf and explained your task specifically for that sample file.

Answer (score 0):

You've only set the meta field, not the PDF content.
Refer to this question: [Editing PDF text using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131031/editing-pdf-text-using-java)

Comment: Its not working. Your examole just adding a text into a pdf. I need to find a particular text and then replace it.

Comment: @Avinash: Did u achieved " find a particular text and then replace " ?