# Read a PDF file and save it again as PDF with Java/Liferay

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, portlet

Can someone give me some idea to read a PDF file to make it editable and then save it again as PDF in Java? Is this possible in a reasonably simple way and without using libraries like itext? It is for a Liferay 6.2 project.

Thank you very much.

Comment: There is no built-in way to edit a PDF in Java, if that's what you're asking. You'll have to use a library such as [iText](https://itextpdf.com/) or [Apache PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131031/editing-pdf-text-using-java) question might help you.

Answer (score 1):

A very convenient way how to do doc conversion in Liferay is to use the open office integration.

```
DocumentConversionUtil.convert(
        String id, InputStream inputStream, String sourceExtension,
        String targetExtension)
```

Just be aware that this may break the PDF UI depending on the character of. If it's just text you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to recover the text of a PDF file with Apache PDFBox. In maven project pom.xml, we must add dependence

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8</version>
</dependency>
```

The code:

```
try {
        DLFileEntry fileEntry = DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.getFileEntry(folder.getGroupId(), folder.getFolderId(), fileName);
        File file = DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.getFile(themeDisplay.getUserId(), fileEntry.getFileEntryId(), fileEntry.getVersion(), true);
        PDDocument pddDocument=PDDocument.load(file);
        PDFTextStripper textStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        String text = textStripper.getText(pddDocument);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

To create a PDF, see the documentation:

https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/cookbook/documentcreation.html