# How to read a BLOB data from database and modify the content of the data before saving it as a file

Tags: java, file, pdf, blob, jdbctemplate

I'm storing a pdf file(`FileInputStream`) in varbinary column of azure sql database from Java. I want to retrieve the blob data and modify few contents and then store it into a pdf again.

Examples I'm seeing in online are related to retrieving and saving it to a pdf using `FileOutputStream`. But I want to modify some contents before storing it into the pdf. How to achieve this?

Link Followed:
https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/jdbc-read-write-blob/

Note: I'm using Spring JdbcTemplate for connecting with azure sql.

Comment: I think the easiest way to modify a PDF file using java code is to use a third party library like _iText_. Refer to [Editing PDF text using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131031/editing-pdf-text-using-java)

Comment: @Abra will check this.. but i'm exploring if any options are available to modify the content right after fetching from blob and before storing it in a pdf.

Comment: Your content is already in PDF format, so you certainly don't want to edit the bytes directly. Do like @Abra suggested, use a PDFReader to read your blob data as a PDF, do whatever changes, and then write it to the file/back to the database